# How to count deleted rows in a H2 database?

Tags: sql, database, h2

I have a simple `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...` statement and I would like to know how many rows have been deleted by executing it. I don't see anything in the [H2 doc](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html) about `NOCOUNT` or `ROWCOUNT` suggested in similar questions. I can exec a `SELECT` with the same condition, but wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: How do you run the delete? From within Java (through JDBC) it will be the return value of the `Statement.executeUpdate()` method.

Comment: I called `Statement.execute()`, `.executeUpdate()` is exactly what I need. Thx!